# How to modify URL when changing month by clicking on the next/before month arrows using bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a Bootstrap Datepicker and I'm trying to be able to modify the url by clicking on the next month arrow or month before arrow.

[Datepicker example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeVKN.png)

When I pick some day on the calendar, the URL changes but I can't figure out how to change the URL by clicking on the arrows too.

My datepicker.js file looks like this:

```
$(function(){

$('#datetable')
        .datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            todayHighlight: true,
            clearBtn: true,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
            changeMonth: false
        })
        .change(function() {
            let pickedDate = $("input").val();
            if (pickedDate){
                $("#showdate").text(
                `You picked ${pickedDate}.`);

                var date = $('#datetable').datepicker('getDate');

                day = date.getDate(date);
                month = date.getMonth(date) + 1;
                year = date.getFullYear(date);

                window.location.assign("https://bloxool-simple.testing.com.co/test/helloworld.php&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day);
            } else {
                $("#showdate").text(
                    `No date chosen.`);
            }
        });
});
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is my working solution:**

```js
$(function () {  
$('#datetable').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayHighlight: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
        changeMonth: false
    }).on("changeMonth", function(e) {
        var date = e.date;
        day = date.getDate();
        month = date.getMonth()+1;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        console.log(day+'/'+month+'/'+year);
        //window.location.assign("https://bloxool-simple.testing.com.co/test/helloworld.php&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day);
     }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
        var date = e.date;
        day = date.getDate();
        month = date.getMonth()+1;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        console.log(day+'/'+month+'/'+year);
        //window.location.assign("https://bloxool-simple.testing.com.co/test/helloworld.php&year=" + year + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>
<div id="datetable">
<input id="reservationDate" type="hidden" placeholder="Choose a date" class="form-control py-4 px-4" />
</div>
```